# VBA Code to Loop Copy/Paste Data for multiple sheets with Unique Table/Sheet Names

Tags: excel, vba

I am fairly new with Excel VBA and am am looking to write a loop that would perform the below function for 11 different sheets/tables.

I made 22 string variables -

- one for each sheet name (11 total.. Q1s-Q11s)
  > only applies to names of the DestWbk Sheets
- one for each table/sheet name (11 total.. Q1-Q11)
  > applies to 3 areas: SrcWbk sheet names, ScrWbk table name, and DestWbk table name (all named exactly the same way).

*Also, the variables "DestWbk" and "ScrWbk" are variables already defined in my code.*

Basically I am going through each sheet, deleting the existing table data in the destination workbook, then pasting the new table data from the source workbook.

```
With DestWbk.Sheets(Q1s).ListObjects(Q1)
    If .ListRows.Count > 0 Then
        .DataBodyRange.Delete
    End If
End With
SrcWbk.Sheets(Q1).Range(Q1).Copy DestWbk.Sheets(Q1s).Range(Q1)
```

I am aware I could create an array with the table name variables (Q1-Q11) to loop through. Same thing for the sheet name variables (Q1s-Q11s). I am just not sure how to loop through both of these variables simultaneously!

Thank you for your technical expertise on this!

Comment: Are there 11 sheets in the workbook with one table on each sheet ? Are the tables actually named Q1, Q2, Q3 etc ?

Comment: Yes, 11 tables with unique names. Q1 is just my name for variable - sorry I was unclear about this! It just happens that the two worksheets have Identical table names (all 11) but their sheet names differ. The source workbook has 11 sheets, each with one table. The sheet name = table name for each. The destination workbook also has 11 sheets, but oddly the sheet names are unique, even though the tables are named EXACTLY the same as on the source workbook!!! Which is why I defined 22 variables (11 x 2)

Answer (score 0):

If the destination sheets are named the same as the source sheets but with 's' added then you don't need to configure any string variables. If they are not then use a dictionary object as a translation table.

update - added error handling

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub copytables()

    Dim SrcWbk As Workbook, DestWbk As Workbook
    Dim SrcWs As Worksheet, DestWs As Worksheet
    Dim SrcTbl As ListObject, DestTbl As ListObject
    
    Set SrcWbk = ThisWorkbook
    Set DestWbk = Workbooks.Open("dest.xlsm")
    
    ' source to destination sheet lookup table
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.Add "Class_1_High_A", "Class 1 High Priority (A)" ' Q1, Q1s
    dict.Add "Class_2_High_A", "Class 2 High Priority (A)" ' Q2, Q2s
    dict.Add "Class_3_High_A", "Class 3 High Priority (A)" ' Q3, Q3s
    ' and so on as many as required
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each SrcWs In SrcWbk.Sheets
        For Each SrcTbl In SrcWs.ListObjects
            If dict.exists(SrcWs.Name) Then
                Set DestTbl = Nothing
                On Error Resume Next
                Set DestTbl = DestWbk.Sheets(dict(SrcWs.Name)).ListObjects(SrcTbl.Name)
                On Error GoTo 0
                If DestTbl Is Nothing Then
                     MsgBox "No destination sheet " & dict(SrcWs.Name) & _
                     " for source sheet " & SrcWs.Name
                Else
                    With DestTbl
                        If .ListRows.Count > 0 Then
                            .DataBodyRange.Delete
                        End If
                        .ListRows.Add
                        SrcTbl.DataBodyRange.Copy .DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1)
                    End With
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox "No destination sheet configured for " & SrcWs.Name
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox DestWbk.Name & " Updated"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response - this is very helpful! There's one thing I didn't explain properly and that's the sheet / table names. The Q1...Q11 and Q1s...Q11s were all defined as variables because each were connected to a different name in my workbook. So Q1 is titled "Class_1_High_A" while Q1s is titled "Class 1 High Priority (A)", etc.

Comment: @Emilyan Ok, see updated code.

Comment: Thank you for the updated code. This is very neat! I am trying to get it to run and I keep getting an error on line "Set DestTbl = DestWbk.Sheets(dict(SrcWs.Name)).ListObjects(SrcTbl.Name)". It says "subscript out of range". Any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: @Emilyan That might mean it can't find the corresponding destination sheet - see updated code.

Comment: Perfect! It works now. Looks like it tripped on the extra sheets I had present in the workbook. Now it simply ignores any sheets not in the dictionary! Thanks so much, I really wish I can become advanced enough to figure out this level of code on my own  the way you did.     PS>>> One last question: how do I edit the code on my own to make it work without the dictionary (aka - I have another workbook where the sheets/tables are in fact 100% identical names). This was the very original code you provided, but sadly I lost it. Thank you again for the great ideas!

Comment: @Emilyan You can edit the dictionary to use the identical codes `dict.Add "Class_1_High_A", "Class_1_High_A"`

Comment: @Emilyan On click on the link "edited 4 hours ago" beneath the post to see previous versions